# JQuery Mobile Pop Transition Failing first time when reading from file on slow device

Tags: jquery-mobile

OK, here is an interesting problem.

I have a project created in JQuery Mobile and it starts with a pop-up displayed with a pop transition. It works well on my desktop browser, but on a low CPU tablet the fist pop-up is not displayed. If I change the transition to none it shows, but then the next pop transition fails.

So what I have discovered is that reading from file:// works, but reading from http:// works on desktop, but fails on tablet.

Refreshing the display (F5) makes it work so it could be something with caching.

Comment: please post code of how you show the popup.

Comment: The code is written in Java using jqm4gwt and compiled with GWT so I don't think it will help much.

Answer (score 0):

Work with callbacks. Probably the function is executing before it's loaded.

Comment: Yes, I suspected something like that. The question is how to make it work. Adding a hard coded delay is not elegant.

Comment: Could you deploy it on a server(like XAMPP)? If your browser is reading from an address like file:// it will never work. Also check in your network tab if every file is loaded. And a code sample will be helpfull.

Comment: Yes, running a server would probably solve the problem at the cost of some extra start-up time. XAMPP would be overkill. NanoHTTPD is a more reasonable alternative.